# cloud function rewrite 302

Tags: google-cloud-functions, firebase-hosting

We have a website that uses firebase rewrites with cloud functions. Depending on my computers or accounts running `firebase deploy --only functions,hosting` results in an error sometimes. The error is 302 with redirect request prompting a login screen: https://us-central1-foo.cloudfunctions.net/_ah/conflogin?continue=https://us-central1-foo.cloudfunctions.net/get-calendars/api/calendars

```
"rewrites": [{
    "source": "/api/calendar",
    "function": "get-calendar"
  }
]
```

I am still not sure what exactly is a root issue but I suspect `firebase deploy` is causing the problem. I have tried deploying the sames files with different settings:
I have accounts A, B and three machines (linux 1, linux 2, mac)

- Deploying on linux 1 with account A has the problem
- Deploying on mac with account A works fine
- Deploying on linux 2 with account B works fine

I created the files for deployment on linux 1. What confuses me is account A works ok on mac but not on linux because I was suspecting an auth or permission issue. Does anyone know what causes my problem?